# I want to run MongoDB on my localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I have recently installed MongoDB through the terminal.
I would like to change my host to localhost instead of their default 127.0.0.1.I know both of them are nearly similar but there is a slight difference between them where localhost is no where connected to the network but the latter which is connected to the network.
How should I do it?
I guess it can be changed in the mongodb.conf.Also should I change the db-path to /data/db??

Please do help me.Thank you in advance![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6fVQ.png)

Comment: Please don't paste images. Use formatted text.

Comment: Your MongoDB already listens `localhost`. `127.0.0.1` is IPv4 protocol

Comment: Do you get any error? If yes, what is the error message?

Comment: I dont want it to listen on 127.0.0.1,instead I want it to listen on local host only

Comment: No.I don't get any sort of error messages